# Calculate Hitting Time between 2 nodes using NetworkX

Tags: python, numpy, graph-theory, networkx, pagerank

I would like to know if i can use `NetworkX` to implement hitting time? Basically I want to calculate the hitting time between any 2 nodes in a graph. My graph is unweighted and undirected. If I understand hitting time correctly, it is very similar to the idea of PageRank.

Any idea how can I implement hitting time using the PageRank method provided by NetworkX?

May I know if there's any good starting point to work with?

I've checked: [MapReduce, Python and NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694237/mapreduce-python-and-networkx)
but not quite sure how it works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need `networkX` to solve the problem, `numpy` can do it if you understand the math behind it. A undirected, unweighted graph can always be represented by a [0,1] adjacency matrix. `nth` powers of this matrix represent the number of steps from `(i,j)` after `n` steps. We can work with a Markov matrix, which is a row normalized form of the adj. matrix. Powers of this matrix represent a random walk over the graph. If the graph is small, you can take powers of the matrix and look at the index `(start, end)` that you are interested in. Make the final state an absorbing one, once the walk hits the spot it can't escape. At each power `n` you get probability that you'll have diffused from `(i,j)`. The hitting time can be computed from this function (as you know the *exact* hit time for discrete steps).

Below is an example with a simple graph defined by the edge list. At the end, I plot this hitting time function. As a reference point, this is the graph used:

[image]

```
from numpy import *

hit_idx = (0,4)

# Define a graph by edge list
edges = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[2,4]]

# Create adj. matrix
A = zeros((5,5))
A[zip(*edges)] = 1
# Undirected condition
A += A.T

# Make the final state an absorbing condition
A[hit_idx[1],:] = 0
A[hit_idx[1],hit_idx[1]] = 1

# Make a proper Markov matrix by row normalizing
A = (A.T/A.sum(axis=1)).T

B = A.copy()
Z = []
for n in xrange(100):
    Z.append( B[hit_idx] )
    B = dot(B,A)

from pylab import *
plot(Z)
xlabel("steps")
ylabel("hit probability")
show()
```

[image]

Comment: WOW. that's one cool answer you have there. So i assume that i need to use the Google Matrix ( or convert my graph into a matrix ) first before performing the hitting time algorithm ?

Comment: networkX has a pagerank method built in: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.link_analysis.html

Comment: @EdChum as I'm not exactly familiar with the pagerank algorithm, how is it related to mean first passage time (what I think the OP is calling hitting time)? I presented this solution as a pedagogic exercise to help anyone one solve the problem in general. Please post the networkx solution if you can show it solves the problem directly so I can see the proper way to solve it using the library.

Comment: @DjangoRocks converting your graph to a matrix is simple, in fact I know that networkX has an output to edges: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_edgelist.html?highlight=edge%20list#networkx.convert.to_edgelist and one to a numpy matrix: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_numpy_matrix.html?highlight=matrix#networkx.convert.to_numpy_matrix

Comment: It probably doesn't relate actually thinking about it as the pagerank includes a teleportation factor that computes the probability that you will escape a page that has no outlinks which is not what you want here as your final state is an absorbing one. @DjangoRocks why do you think PageRank is relevant here? Also MapReduce is just a technique to parallelise the computation of a taks across nodes in a network and it depends on your algorithm as to whether the tasks can be performed independently, is this true for what you are attempting?

Comment: @EdChum ok this may sound stupid, but my professor explained the concept of hitting time using PageRank. so i thought Hitting Time is related to PageRank.